# How to remove table data based on comparison between different columns in another table in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, datetime, matlab-table

I have 2 tables in MATLAB- table A and table B, each having different dimensions (different no. of rows and columns). The first column of table A has the Date and time in format like `2018-11-01 12:00:00` (DateTime data format).

Now, in Table B, the Third and Fourth Column also consist of Date and Time in format like `2018-11-01 01:11:12:173000`. What I would like to achieve is to remove all the rows (which are the data instances) from Table A, in case of which the Datetime for Table A falls in the range between the Date and Time in Table B. (To be more precise, suppose Table B has an entry of DateTime in third column for the first row/first data instance as `2018-11-10 12:30:00:173` and in fourth column as `2018-11-10 12:40:00:145`, I would like to remove all data entries/rows from Table A, in case of which the DateTime Column value for Table A falls in the range of `2018-11-10 12:30:00:173` to `2018-11-10 12:40:00:145`, as an example). This means that basically I would be removing the data in the aforesaid range from the Table A.

To approach this, the first thing which comes to my mind is to use `inner join()`, but, it is evident from Mathworks Community guidance that `innerjoin()` only matches the exact column value which I specify the Key as, but in this case, I would be looking at a range of DateTime values in 2 columns of table B, so perhaps this might not be the best approach. Using a `for loop` for this purpose might as well work, but would be quite complex and redundant with huge computational time on the large data in the tables. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.isbetween.html?

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received some good answers to the question on the Mathworks Community page and the answers can be found at https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/432509-how-to-remove-table-data-based-on-comparison-between-different-columns-in-another-table-in-matlab?s_tid=prof_contriblnk

**I appreciate the answer by Guillaume (answered on the Mathworks Community page link mentioned above) and am putting it down here for future help to anyone:-**

```
%inputs: TableA with a column named date, TableB with a column named datestart and dateend
%replace by actual table and variable names.
datetocheck = repmat(TableA.date, 1, height(TableB));  %replicate in as many columns as there are rows in B
datestart = repmat(TableB.datestart', height(TableA), 1); %tranpose and replicate in as many rows as in A
dateend = repmat(TableB.dateend', height(TableA), 1);
toremove = any(datetocheck >= datestart & datetocheck <= dateend, 2); 
TableA(toremove, :) = [];
```